# Sum Fields in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, sum, pivot-table

I have a document with Column A (Date) and Column B (Hours). I created a Pivot Table on another sheet, and it's doing an okay job of showing the data:

```
6/1/2014
    2
    1.25
6/2/2014
    3
    0.25
6/3/2014
    4
    3.5
```

What I would like it to do is SUM the hours, so it looks like this:

```
6/1/2014
    3.25
6/2/2014
    3.25
6/3/2014
    7.5
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the hours from being a `Row` field to a `Value` field:

[image]

Comment: Note: If you really need the hours to be in the same column as the dates, that will require some trickery, at best. I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I am noticing that these tables don't update when I change the original data. Can these not keep running sums?

Comment: Pivot tables need to be refreshed. There's a lot of data cached behind the scenes, and you wouldn't want it refreshing automatically. Just hit the refresh button.